# Как добавить что то к уже существующему массиву?

Tags: c#, массивы

Написал следующий код для добавления элементов в уже объявленный массив:

```
static void Main() {
    string [] test1 = {"test", "test2"};
    string [] test1 = new string {"test3", "test4"};
    foreach(string x in test1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
  }
```

В ответ получаю ошибку:

```
main.cs(5,15): error CS0128: A local variable named "test1" is already defined in this scope
```

Извиняюсь за, возможно, слишком глупый вопрос (просто я только учу массивы).

Comment: внутри одного метода не могут существовать две локальные переменные с одинаковым именем. У вас 2 переменные с именем `test1`

Comment: а как иначе добавить информацию в уже обьявленный масив?

Comment: массивы это нерасширяемая структура данных, если вам нужно добавить элементы лучше использовать списки

Comment: @iiKuzmychov нерасширяемая. С изменяемостью-то у массива всё в порядке...

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы правы, неверное слово подобрал, имел ввиду неизменяемых размеров

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Количество элементов массива задается при его создании, и не может быть изменено. Это связано с особенностями работы с памятью компьютера, нельзя просто так изменить размер выделенного участка памяти. А массив - это строго непрерывный участок памяти. Не может быть половина массива в одном углу оперативы, а вторая в другом.

Чтобы "изменить" размер массива, надо создать новый массив нужного размера и скопировать туда данные из старого.

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] test1 = { "test", "test2" };
    string[] test2 = new string[4];

    test2[0] = test1[0];
    test2[1] = test1[1];
    test2[2] = "test3";
    test2[3] = "test4";

    foreach (string x in test2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Вот и всё, никакой магии.

Еще есть метод `Array.Resize`, он немного упрощает процесс.

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] test1 = { "test", "test2" };
    
    Array.Resize(ref test1, 4);

    test1[2] = "test3";
    test1[3] = "test4";

    foreach (string x in test1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

С первого взгляда может показаться, что он таки изменяет размер массива, но на деле он делает ровно то же самое, что я сделал в первом фрагменте кода - создает новый массив и копирует данные из старого, и ссылку на новый массив помещает в старую переменную. Точно так же, магии нет.

Есть еще коллекции изменяемых размеров, например `List<T>`, в него можно добавлять элементы и удалять, вообще любые действия с составом элементов списка выполнять, но внутри него те же массивы, он их по-хитрому пересоздает и копирует данные, чтобы вам было удобно работать с динамическим составом коллекции.

```
static void Main()
{
    List<string> test1 = new List<string> { "test", "test2" };

    test1.Add("test3");
    test1.Add("test4");

    foreach (string x in test1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Внутри одного метода не могут существовать две локальные переменные с одинаковым именем. У вас в `Main` 2-е переменные с именем `test1`.

Насчёт массивов: изменить размеры массива нельзя, его размер фиксирован и задаётся при инициализации. Можно только создать новый массив и скопировать туда элементы из старого, дополнив новыми. Но для подобных задач лучше подходят такие коллекции, как списки.